# Building custom Shapes in Konva

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

I've been asked to build something similar to this so that customers can draw basics shapes of kitchen tops.  Similar to that in the image below but also have dimensions.

It looks like konva has support for basic shapes like rectangle and circle etc and it also includes a transformer which allows for resizing.  However, I think if I want to build a custom shape like the one in green and have individual sizing i.e. resize each individual line.  I am going to have to build something myself.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  I have seen an example where someone has used a "line" class which takes a series of points and then sets the attribute to closed which fills in the shape.  Obviously I would need to extend this to allow the custom resizing.  However, Im not sure this is the correct path to head down?

Any suggestions?

.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about using rectangles and having an option to snap them together.  It should be fairly simple to do the edge detection and snapping. Then show the result as a Konva.Line around the perimeter.

Then you can show all the control handles for the rectangles except those on the sides where another Rect has joined.

Comment: I am a developer but havent used konajs previously.  I've had a quick peruse over the API and had a look at some of the code in github.

Comment: So with your idea I kind of understand what you mean but not sure on how to implement it.... so your suggestion is to have multiple rectangles with no stroke and then create a line which goes around the perimeter of the two rectangles to create the stroke?

Then with the control handles I'm not sure how these would appear?  Have to manually add these as well as small rect's ?

Comment: When you say edge detection and snapping - do you mean when two rectangles get close together then join them to create 1 shape?  If that is the case then I dont think its required... basically I will have some predefined shapes that I will just put onto the canvas and they can resize the shape to desired dimensions.

Comment: Yes exactly that with edge detection and snapping. Make move them together is the edges get close. So from user's perspective that snap together in position.

Comment: As for the control handles you can use the Konva.Transformer() to create the handles using the enabledAnchors to show/hide certain handles. Or you can as you say create your own draggable Konva.Rect (s)

Comment: Suppose it all depends on how flexible the kitchen tops are in terms of depth. I.e can customer create a kitchen top of any depth or are there set depths they choose. If set depths then predefined shapes probably better approach.

Comment: Thanks for all your info....I think realistically reusing the transformer will be the easier solution but I might need to override it to reposition some of the locations of them as I would need them to appear in the middle of any line.  Am I right in thinking scenefunc is the drawing method?

Comment: If you use hidden (from users perspective) rectangles as the nodes for transformer. You they should all be in center.

Comment: Yes scenefunc gives you more direct access to canvas context. It allows more flexibility to draw your own custom shapes. But for control handles (assuming you want handles like in your example then Rect will work well. Just create your own control handles use rects with its position and dragstart, dragmove and dragend should achieve what you need.